# create-next-app project : react-script is not recognized when running " npm run build "

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, package.json

This is my package.json file:

```
  "name": "food-recipe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.4.0",
    "contentful": "^9.0.3",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
}
```

when I run : npm build
this error is shown.
[image]

Comment: Try installing it with `npm i --save react-scripts`

Comment: i did it but another error came up: Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html

Comment: `react-scripts` is used for CRA apps. In a Next.js app you should use `next build` instead.

Comment: I rebuilt the app from scratch and it came up with different error. could you please have a look I posted the issue here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505993/next-build-create-next-app-not-working-when-deploying-to-vercel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need react-scripts when using create-next-app
instead of :

```
"build": "react-scripts build",
```

do this :

```
"build": "next build",
```