# "next build" (create-next-app) not working when deploying to Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, contentful

I am running through an error while trying to deploy the app to Vercel.
The issue mainly happens when trying to run next build because it is working fine on my localhost:3000.
This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "foodrecipe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.4.0",
    "contentful": "^9.0.3",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2"
  }
}
```

This is the complete log:

[image]

[image]

These are getStaticPaths/props functions in [slug].js:

```
  const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID ,  
    accessToken:process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY 
  })

  export const getStaticPaths = async()=>{
    const response = await client.getEntries({content_type:'recipesReactjs'})

    const paths = response.items.map(item =>{
      return{
        params:{slug: item.fields.slug}
      }
    })
    return{
      paths:paths,
      fallback:true, 
    }
  }

  export const getStaticProps = async(context)=>{ 
    const response = await client.getEntries({
      content_type:'recipesReactjs',
      'fields.slug':context.params.slug,
    })

    if(!response.items.length){
      return{
        redirect:{
          destination:'/', 
          permanant:false  
        }
      }
    }

    return{
      props:{myRecipe: response.items[0]},
      revalidate:1 , 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you notice any warnings in your local server? If so, make sure to fix all those warnings before deploying to vercel.

Comment: There are no warnings at all.

Comment: Isn't it just a Warning, not an Error? You can just ignore it if the build is succesful

Comment: it can't be ignored, I want to deploy it. when I am trying to deploy it on vercel, I get that error shown in the image.

Comment: Could you share the complete log?

Comment: I've just added the complete logs in a format of images

Comment: That still doesn't fully show the error. It looks like it's being generated from `contentful` usage inside `getStaticPaths` in the `/pages/recipes/[slug]` page. Can you show us the full error (from the beginning), and also show your `getStaticPaths` function?

Comment: yes, sure. I edited the post and added functions of getStaticPaths / Props in [slug].js

Comment: Looks like the `client.getEntries` call is causing the error. Do you have `CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID` and `CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY` env variables properly set up in Vercel?

Comment: Yes, I set them up correctly and just doubled check now. still the same error
The error is also happening when I run build locally so probably the Env variables not an issue.